# How to run simple scripts with Scala?

Tags: scala, scripting, scala-cli

I have installed Scala (on an air-gapped linux machine from the scala3-3.3.1.tar.gz).

I try to run a simple Scala program without `sbt`. So I wrote a file `hello.scala`

```scala
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println("Hello, World")
  }
}
```

and then invoked

```
scala hello.scala
```

This works. :-)

But I looked through the Scala 3 website and saw many examples of code without the whole "object wrapping". So I was hoping to write the simpler file `script.scala`

```scala
println("Hello, World")
```

and run it with `scala`. But this does not work: Scala returns the error "Illegal start of toplevel definition".

How can I run this? Do I need some command line option for this? Or do I need `scala-cli`? (I have read `scala` has become or will become `scala-cli`.)

I'm confused. What is the best way to run simple Scala scripts on an air-gapped machine.

Comment: If you want to run **Scala** scripts, use **Scala-cli**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Scala 3 does not support *script mode*](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-feature-requests/issues/38). There is an open [Scala Improvement Process (SIP)](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/) issue about [adding back some of the features of the old Scala 2 `scala` runner](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/scala-cli.html).

The way this is going to be implemented is by merging some of the code from [Scala CLI](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/scripting/), which includes a script runner (among many other things).

The good news is: You don't have to wait for SIP-42 to be implemented, since Scala CLI exists and works *right now*. Scala CLI scripting has a lot of features that the old script runner didn't have, such as loading additional code or specifying a particular Scala version via the `//> using` directive.

Note that, if I am not mistaken, the code you showed was *never* legal *Scala* code. It was a special *sub-variant* of Scala, which was *only* accepted by the script runner integrated into the `scala` command. This may seem like a technicality, but that is the reason why this is not documented as an incompatibility in the Scala language: it was never part of the Scala language.

If you don't want to use Scala 2 or Scala CLI, [Scala 3 has massively improved the syntax for writing main methods](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/methods-main-methods.html), so the example is not nearly as verbose as the example in your question. In Scala 3, your code would look like this:

```scala
@main def main = println("Hello, World")
```

Note that the name of the method can be anything, so if you want to make it shorter:

```scala
@main def _ = println("Hello, World")
```

Main methods have some cool features, for example, [you can get command line argument parsing for free, just by defining parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/methods-main-methods.html#command-line-arguments):

```scala
@main def add(a: Int, b: Int) = println(a + b)
```

```sh
scala add 3 4
# 7

scala add 3 four
# Illegal command line: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "four"
```

Scala will take the names and types of your parameters and generate command line argument parsing code for you, including error handling and reporting.

Comment: Cool, that defining functions in Scala 3 is so concisely possible. Thanks for this. Re `scala-cli`, can it be used on an air-gapped machine or does it (like `sbt`) always try to download stuff from the internet?

Comment: @halloleo there is an offline mode, if it does not work as expected please don't hesitate to file an issue on GH :)
https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/guides/power/offline/